# Netlify "build.command" failed: Error message Command failed with exit code 255: hugo --gc --minify -b $URL

Tags: netlify

```
2:35:02 PM: "build.command" failed                                        
2:35:02 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2:35:02 PM: ​
2:35:02 PM:   Error message
2:35:02 PM:   Command failed with exit code 255: hugo --gc --minify -b $URL (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-255)
2:35:02 PM: ​
2:35:02 PM:   Error location
2:35:02 PM:   In build.command from netlify.toml:
2:35:02 PM:   hugo --gc --minify -b $URL
2:35:02 PM: ​
2:35:02 PM:   Resolved config
2:35:02 PM:   build:
2:35:02 PM:     command: hugo --gc --minify -b $URL
2:35:02 PM:     commandOrigin: config
2:35:02 PM:     environment:
2:35:02 PM:       - CI
2:35:02 PM:       - HUGO_VERSION
2:35:02 PM:       - HUGO_ENABLEGITINFO
2:35:02 PM:       - HUGO_ENV
2:35:02 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/public
2:35:02 PM:     publishOrigin: config
2:35:02 PM:   plugins:
2:35:02 PM:     - inputs:
2:35:02 PM:         debug: true
2:35:02 PM:       origin: config
2:35:02 PM:       package: netlify-plugin-hugo-cache-resources
2:35:03 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
2:35:04 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
2:35:04 PM: Finished processing build request in 30.282s
```

Last time I commit successfully to the netlify is November last year. But this time I can't update the website anymore. How should I revise my **netlify.toml** according to this issue? Do I need to revise other?

My current netlify.toml file:

```
[build]
  command = "hugo --gc --minify -b $URL"
  publish = "public"

[build.environment]
  HUGO_VERSION = "0.102.3"
  HUGO_ENABLEGITINFO = "true"

[context.production.environment]
  HUGO_ENV = "production"

[context.deploy-preview]
  command = "hugo --gc --minify --buildFuture -b $DEPLOY_PRIME_URL"

[context.branch-deploy]
  command = "hugo --gc --minify -b $DEPLOY_PRIME_URL"

[[plugins]]
  package = "netlify-plugin-hugo-cache-resources"
  [plugins.inputs]
    debug = true
```

If necessary, please view [my github link of this folder](https://github.com/Anran0716/AnranZheng/tree/master).

Thank you so much for any help :)